# Why is withContext returning a nullable object?

Tags: kotlin

In the following function:

```
suspend fun loadData(filename: String): MyData {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            loader.loadJsonFromFile(filename)?.let { json ->
                Gson().fromJson<MyData>(
                    jsonStr,
                    object : TypeToken<MyData>() {}.type
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler complains that withContext is returning a nullable type MyData?, but the signature of withContext looks like

```
public suspend fun <T> withContext(
    context: CoroutineContext,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): T
```

And I've defined T as MyData (non-nullable).  Why is the compiler giving me an error and can I write this function without using a var in its body?

Answer (score 5):

You haven't defined `T`, compiler inferred it for you (I mean the `T` in the `withContext`). Since the lambda passed to the `withContext` may return null if `loadJsonFromFile` returns `null`, so can `withContext`, and compiler infers, quite correctly, `T` as `MyData?`.